# NDJSON stream with an AutoRest generated C# ServiceClient

Tags: c#, autorest

Using AutoRest, I've generated a C# ServiceClient for a service that supports long polling type operations, by streaming NDJSON events.

The swagger document for the service defines a `produces` element in the path:

```
"/apis/thisisastreamingendpoint": {
    produces: ["application/json;stream=watch"]
```

Is there anything in the AutoRest configuration that will allow to generate a client that will support this streaming behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for streaming endpoints in AutoRest: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2650, although the team there are looking into adding better support for long running operations in future, so perhaps it will be added.